# Unity GUI.Box not showing up after if statement

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Can anyone tell me why my Inventory box is not showing up?  If the user presses the Inventory button I want the inventory box to show up.  I'm not getting any errors and if I place the inventory box outside of the if statement it works fine.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyGUI : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnGUI () {

        // Make a background for the button

        GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 200), "Menu");

        // Make a button.  
        // Be able to click that button.
        // If they click it return inventory screen.

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect(20, 50, 75, 20), "Inventory")) {

            Debug.Log("Your inventory opens");

            GUI.Box (new Rect (150, 10, 300, 200), "Inventory");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inventory box isn't showing up because the OnGUI function is called every frame, like Update. This means that your inventory rectangle only gets drawn during that on OnGUI call that happens when the inventory button is clicked.

You could use a boolean flag to fix your problem.

```
private bool _isInvetoryOpen = false;

void OnGUI () {
    GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 200), "Menu");

    // Toggle _isInventoryOpen flag on Inventory button click.
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (20, 50, 75, 20), "Inventory")) {
        _isInvetoryOpen = !_isInvetoryOpen;
    }

    // If _isInventoryOpen is true, draw the invetory rectangle.
    if (_isInvetoryOpen) {
        GUI.Box (new Rect (150, 10, 300, 200), "Inventory");
    }
}
```

The flag is toggled when the inventory button is clicked and continues to be drawn or not drawn during the following OnGUI calls.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Basics.html

Comment: Thanks so much! So I understand why my version wasn't working but why does the inventory button disappear when the button is clicked a second time? Is it because the OnGUI is reset and makes an entirely new view?  That seems like it would waste a lot of memory?

Comment: The OnGUI function is redrawing each cycle and the button is set up to toggle the _isInventoryOpen when it is clicked. So, when _isInventoryOpen is false, the Inventory box is not drawn. It doesn't really have a big impact on memory but it does have a huge impact on the CPU. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13433/performance-differences-in-unitygui-versus-guitext.html

Answer (score 0):

@davidjheberle is correct in that this is because of the repeated nature of calls to `OnGUI`; but it's worth mentioning that with modern Unity, you can also use a `GUI.RepeatButton`. `GUI.RepeatButton` is almost identical to `GUI.Button`, save that the status of the mouse button being down over it is checked for *every single frame*, not just the frame of the initial click. So, at least for Unity 2020.3 and thereabouts, the following code would also work:

```
    void OnGUI () {

    GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 200), "Menu");

    //Note the difference here-- we are using a RepeatButton instead
    if (GUI.RepeatButton (new Rect(20, 50, 75, 20), "Inventory")) {

        Debug.Log("Your inventory opens");

        GUI.Box (new Rect (150, 10, 300, 200), "Inventory");

    }

}
```